# Unable to retrieve image names correctly

Tags: php

Im trying to retrieve an array of images. All images are appearing fine. However,images with name "image_01" and "image_02" are being retrieved as image_1 and image_2. It is because of the "str_replace" Im using. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

```
$image=$policy->gallery;     
$image = trim($image,'*');
$temp = explode('*',$image );
echo $temp[5];
// $temp = array_filter($temp);
foreach($temp as $image)
{
  $images[]=base_url()."images/park_photos/".trim( str_replace( array('['*']') ,"" ,$image ) );
  //echo trim( str_replace( array('['*']') ,"" ,$image ));
}
foreach($images as $image)
{
  echo "<img src='{$image}' style='width:100px; height:100px; display:block; float:left;' />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but what you want to replace with str_replace( array('['*']')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix it, you need to replace

```
$images[]=base_url()."images/park_photos/".trim( str_replace( array('['*']') ,"" ,$image ) );
```

with

```
$images[] = base_url() . trim($image);
```

or even with

```
$images[] = base_url() . $image;
```

---

What's happening? I guess that with this `str_replace` you wanted to make sure that `*` is removed from picture name. But you did it before already (`$temp = explode('*',$image );`) so no need to duplicate.

Now, why does `0` get removed from picture name? There's some "magic" happening in `array('['*']')`. The `*` character is interpreted as multiplication, because of the quotation marks sequence. To understand, try doing this:

```
$a = '['*']';
var_dump($a);
// outputs: int(0)
```

Why? PHP is guessing variables types from context. The context in this case is: multiply `'['` by `']'`. Since multiplication applies to numbers, PHP casts the two strings (`'['` and `']'`) to integers, zeros specifically. (Read more about [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)).
So, `str_replace( array('['*']') ,"" ,$image )` equals `str_replace( array(0) ,"" ,$image )` - that is "replace zeros with empty string.